# How to filter twitter streaming API feed to get only news related items?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am building an app, that currently uses twitter streaming api to find football club related news. But I only want those tweets which are related to football club news. As of now I am getting every tweet that has the football club name. And some times these results are irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You need to teach your app the difference between "football club news" and "irrelevant".  This is a field of research under the general topic of "machine learning".  Unless the content providers give you message tags that solve your specific request, I'm afraid that you're stuck with building and refining a trained model to classify the articles found.

There are two basic approaches to this:

1. Analyze your own decision processes: out of all the messages you see with your initial filter, how do *you* determine what is relevant?  What factors are involved?  Write code to embody that.
2. Classify a large sample of messages as "good" or "bad".  Feed those classifications into a deep-learning engine appropriate to your task (text processing, perhaps a convolutional neural network).  Save the trained model and call it as part of your app.

Of course, there's the old way of doing this: have a row of paid staffers who read and classify articles that the filter brings up.  Post those messages to your app's input buffer.